# CSS column-count makes center column larger

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to create an unordered list with three columns, displayed as:

```
item      item      item
item      item      item
item      item      item
item      item      item
item
```

Instead, I get a list that looks like this:

```
item      item      item
item      item      item
item      item      item
item      item      item
          item
```

Except it looks even worse, because the columns are centered horizontally. In the css file:

```
ul.three-cols {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
```

How can I make the items align at the top and also make the list fill the first column first?

EDIT: this is the code in the html.erb file:

```
        <ul class="three-cols">
          <% @birds.each do |bird| %>
            <li>
              <h5><%= link_to bird.name, bird_path(bird) %></h5>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I don't understand how you got that result, can you put up a code snippet ?

Comment: It is part of a rails project with bootstrap installed, can this explain the problem?

Comment: the framework don't matter and gives no clue since is a matter of CSS and html only, You can run your app, then open the console and copy the appropriate html and css over, when i try to recreate it with what you provided it answer your question https://jsfiddle.net/m0pfv9u5/

Comment: The html is the same, except there is a <h5> tag inside each <li>. What I can see when I inspect the <ul> is that display is set to block, I am guessing this comes from bootstrap. There are some other properties set for ul as well: margin-block-start, margin-block-end, margine-inline-start, margin-inline-end, padding-inline-start

Comment: If you can't provide a code snippet that illustrates the issue, I'm not sure anyone can help you

Answer (score 0):

It is because the H5 tag in your LI needs to be set to display:inline-block;

It is being rendered as block so is breaking the layout;